# How will my CNN results be affected by large discrepancies between the number of samples in some of the classes?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, dataset, image-classification, computer-vision

The number of samples in my dataset range between 3800 and 100,000 per class. Was wondering if my neural network will be more biased towards the classes with a higher number of images. I'm trying on the pretrained resnet152V2 model from Keras.

Comment: Highly relevant: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en I realize you didn’t ask about resampling, balancing, or SMOTE, but those are common approach to this non-problem. // In sort, the answer is that imbalance will affect your predictions, and it **should** affect your predictions!

Answer (score 0):

That is an empirical question that can could be answered qualitatively with experimentation. You can train one version with unequal number samples and train another version with equal number of samples. The results between these two versions can be compared to see how bias is due to class imbalances.